# how to remove prefix from my primary key in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have **users** table which contains UserId as primary key but when I user Authentication it uses **"Users.user_UserId"**
so how do i remove "user_" prefix from primary key?

**Model:**

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */

        protected $table = 'Users';

        protected $primaryKey = 'UserId';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config/auth.php in provider array uncomment the user at line number 73.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'users' => [
             'driver' => 'database',
             'table' => 'users',
         ],
    ],
```